# How do I create and save to a text file using PHP?

Tags: php, text

I've been working on a quiz, and I've come across the need to save my answers to a text file. I've come up with some code:

```
<?php
    $myfile = fopen("myfile.txt", "r+") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $txt = "Name:\n";
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    $txt = "Student1\n";
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    $txt = "Marks:\n";
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    $txt = "0\n";
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    echo fread($myfile,filesize("myfile.txt"));
    fclose($myfile);
?>
```

But I've noticed that this only wants to write to a file with content that is already there, and it fails to create a new file and write to it. Is there any way this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `w+` instead of `r+`

```
$myfile = fopen("myfile.txt", "w+")
```